# Array Handling from PHP to Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, bootstrap-modal, filemaker

I have this array that I generated in PHP and stored into a variable called "$auction_additionalrevenues".  With said array I have generated, a very nice data table using bootstrap.

My ultimate goal is to allow the user to click a row in said data table and then use a modal to allow them to edit (then next create a row in the table).

I have done this many times using FileMaker as the db source where the rows in the table are "related data" or child records to the parent record the user is viewing.  This time around, the data is not related, but rather in the parent record itself in "repeating fields" from which I have created a multi-dimensional array.

What I can't seem to get right in this particular instance is how to show the user the data in the model for the specific row they have clicked.  It's frustrating because I have ALL the data in that multi-deminensional (or nested?) PHP array stored in the global variable.  In other words, I don't have to go back to the DB to get that data as it is already in the array/variable.

How do I pass all this data between the rendered page/Javascript/PHP?  I can easily echo the record/row of the into JS via an "onclick" as below.

onClick=showadrev()

When I do that I can write the $mkey ($mkey = index/row) to the console log or alert it out no problem.

Next I want that modal popover to show the array that is nested at that index/row.

Here is my array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
        [0] => Raffle
        [1] => Pick of Live
        [2] => 
        [3] => 100
        [4] => 150
        [5] => Cocktail Only
        [6] => Struggled a bit, offered some from the stage to hit the minimum
    )

    [1] => Array
    (
        [0] => Raffle
        [1] => Ticket/Tangible
        [2] => $1000 gift certificate to Canlis
        [3] => 25
        [4] => Unlimited
        [5] => Cocktail Only
        [6] => Really don't know how this did, but the box was pretty full of tickets
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [0] => Game
        [1] => Ticket/Tangible
        [2] => The Horse Race. Everyone is a winner. Receive a gift certificate ranging from $25 to $99.
        [3] => 25
        [4] => Unlimited
        [5] => Cocktail Only
        [6] => Great participation
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [0] => Other
        [1] => Mystery/ Blind Pull
        [2] => Wine Pull
        [3] => 25
        [4] => 50
        [5] => cocktail only
        [6] => There was about a dozen or so left
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [0] => Other
        [1] => Ticket/Tangible
        [2] => Centerpiece sales
        [3] => 25
        [4] => 35
        [5] => Pre & During
        [6] => Unknown
    )
```

)

And here is the Data Table I am rendering:

```
<div class="wizard-step-3">
    <fieldset>
        <legend class="pull-left width-full">Aditional Revenue</legend>
        <!-- <div class="table-responsive"> -->
        <table id="data-table" class="table table-bordered table-striped" width="100%">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Item</th>
                    <th>Type</th>
                    <th>Title</th>
                    <th>Price</th>
                    <th>Total Available</th>
                    <th>Sold By</th>
                    <th>Description</th>
                    <th>How did it Go?</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <?php foreach ($auction_additionalrevenues as $mkey => $adrevitems){
                    $no = $mkey + 1;
                    ?><tr style="cursor:pointer;" onClick=showadrev(<?php echo $mkey ; ?>)><?php;
                    echo '<td>'.$no.'</td>';
                    echo '<td>'.$adrevitems[0].'</td>';
                    echo '<td>'.$adrevitems[1].'</td>';
                    echo '<td>'.$adrevitems[3].'</td>';
                    echo '<td>'.$adrevitems[4].'</td>';
                    echo '<td>'.$adrevitems[5].'</td>';
                    echo '<td>'.$adrevitems[2].'</td>';
                    echo '<td>'.$adrevitems[6].'</td>';
                    echo '</tr>';

            } ?>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <!-- </div> -->
    </fieldset>
</div>
```

Comment: If I pass the array directly to the JS (along with the "mkey") without json_encode I get "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0" and yet if I pass it to the JS with json_encode I get "Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token" in the console log.

Comment: Are you asking how to put the whole array in a javascript variable ?  such as `var data = [[Raffle,..],....]`

Comment: also, if I alert out the "typeof" I get "Function"

Comment: Thank you ArtisticPhoenix!  I am willing to pass the whole array into JS but haven't had any luck with that either.  I want the user to click row three in the dat table and get a model where they can edit the data for that row.  I can seem to pass this data around properly.

Comment: You can do this if so `var data = <?php echo json_encode( $array ); ?>;` this should be fine as long as you don't have line returns in your data.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
     var data = <?php echo json_encode( $array ); ?>;
</script>
```

The json data will look like this

```
  [["Raffle","Pick of Live","",100,150,"Cocktail Only", "Struggled a bit, offered some from the stage to hit the minimum"], .... ]
```

Which will/should be a valid Javascript array as long as there is no line returns in it.  You'll want to make sure your not json encoding something like false if you pull it from the DB `json_encode(false)` instead of an actual array.

So if you insert this into the page you basically get something like this.

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
     var data = [["Raffle","Pick of Live","",100,150,"Cocktail Only", "Struggled a bit, offered some from the stage to hit the minimum"], .... ];
</script>
```

I'm not sure if that is what you want though, you may also be able to  add it into the table using the data attribute like this

```
   <td class="data_row" data-array="<?php echo implode(',', $array[0]); ?>" >
```

Then you can get it by selecting that td, pulling out the data and using split.

```
 var rowData = $('td.data_row').data('array').split(',');
```

Implode will make it a comma separated list, and split is simular to PHP's explode, to make it back into an array.  Although, I am not really sure if you can put an array directly into the data attribute ( I doubt it though ) and avoid doing that.

If you want the keys too, its a tad bit harder because in JS they will be objects but in that case you need to pull them out of the DB or what have you first. ( associative array VS JS object )

Alternately with the structure you have you could do something like this with jQuery,

```
$('tr.row').click( function(event) {
      var rowData = [];
     $(this).find('td').each( function(i,v){
          rowData.push($(this).text());
     });

     //do somthing with rowData
 });
```

Which is basically find click the row ( added a class of row to make it easier) then find all the child td's then loop and add the text in them to an array.

Comment: Keep in mind that you could end up with JavaScript like this: `var data = ;` which would crash your app due to syntax error.

Comment: Granted, but it's unlikely if it came from the DB, you can just do `$array = []; while( $row = $PDO->fetch(PDO:FETCH_ARRAY)){ $array [] = $row; }`  Then their is always a default array even if its empty. :-)   But it is something to be validated in PHP before hand.  I did add a bit in for that just now, Thanks!

Comment: Exactly my point. You're making way too many assumptions about the PHP code that generated `$array`. I think a more defensive approach when passing it to JS would be to safe-guard it and prove that the JS would never crash because of that...

Answer (score 0):

Artistics answer should be the accepted answer for this. Here is how I implemented it.

```
//echo $system_id;
//echo $system_auth_id;
print_r(json_encode($AuthData));
```

I left the commented out stuff so that you see what I was doing before I read this and realized I needed to encode on the PHP side prior to sending it to my JS app.

Result:

```
[{"system_id":"61a694d0-3605-4502-952b-38d87b451a56","system_auth_id":"caa5906f-d9ae-4297-8e9f-5ea8d9ed8b51","system_lastauth_id":"ace681bb-48f5-4831-a23d-6608c696f264","system_rundate":"2019-04-27T22:46:07.090Z","system_auth_lastrundate":"2019-04-27T22:45:57.932Z","system_auth_updated_func":"main_init_auth_extend","system_auth_lastupdateddate":"2019-04-27T22:45:57.932Z","system_auth_lastupdated_func":"main_init_auth_extend","system_auth_request":"0","system_auth_request_lastfunc":"n\/a","system_auth_denials":"0","system_auth_denial_lastfunc":"n\/a","system_auth_success":"0","system_auth_success_lastfunc":"n\/a"}]
```

Previous Result:

```
Array( [0] => stdClass Object ( [system_id] => 61a694d0-3605-4502-952b-38d87b451a56 [system_auth_id] => caa5906f-d9ae-4297-8e9f-5ea8d9ed8b51 [system_lastauth_id] => ace681bb-48f5-4831-a23d-6608c696f264 [system_rundate] => 2019-04-27T22:46:07.090Z [system_auth_lastrundate] => 2019-04-27T22:45:57.932Z [system_auth_updated_func] => main_init_auth_extend [system_auth_lastupdateddate] => 2019-04-27T22:45:57.932Z [system_auth_lastupdated_func] => main_init_auth_extend [system_auth_request] => 0 [system_auth_request_lastfunc] => n/a [system_auth_denials] => 0 [system_auth_denial_lastfunc] => n/a [system_auth_success] => 0 [system_auth_success_lastfunc] => n/a ) )
```